# Como pegar todo o HTML dessa página como uma string?

Tags: c#, html5, webrequest

Eu estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade e com isso tentando ler o HTML de uma página do bradesco([Link que eu quero o HTML aqui](https://wwwss.shopinvest.com.br/infofundos/fundos/TabelaRentabilidade.do?cdSgmtoProdt=1))

O problema é que eu não consigo o HTML que está dentro dos frames e eu não sei como conseguir pegar ele.

Atualmente o que eu estou tentando fazer para pegar o HTML é:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1325423423423
{
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "https://wwwss.shopinvest.com.br/infofundos/fundos/TabelaRentabilidade.do?cdSgmtoProdt=1";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        request.Accept = "application/json";

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
}
```

E o retorno na resposta do servidor é:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basicamente, o que eu preciso é uma maneira de conseguir o HTML dentro da tag de frame com o name frmMeio.

```
<frame name="frmMeio" src="ConteudoTabelaRentabilidade.do?cdSgmtoProdt=1">
```

Comment: Não sei se ajuda, mas você tentou mudar a variável `url` para pegar somente os dados da tabela de rentabilidade? Algo do tipo: `string url = "https://wwwss.shopinvest.com.br/infofundos/fundos/ConteudoTabelaRentabilidade.do?cdSgmtoProdt=1";` O resultado que você irá obter é [esse aqui](https://wwwss.shopinvest.com.br/infofundos/fundos/ConteudoTabelaRentabilidade.do?cdSgmtoProdt=1).

Comment: parceiro, posta isso como pergunta pra eu te dar os creditos!

Comment: Eu tinha tentado colocar a url + "\ConteudoTabelaRentabilidade.do?cdSgmtoProdt=1", mas não tinha chego a tentar isso! Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme o comentário, a solução é mudar a variável `url` para pegar somente os dados da tabela de rentabilidade, que estão contidos no `iframe`.

A linha de comando fica da seguinte forma:

`string url ="https://wwwss.shopinvest.com.br/infofundos/fundos/ConteudoTabelaRentabilidade.d‌​o?cdSgmtoProdt=1";`

O resultado obtido com a alteração pode ser acessado [aqui](https://wwwss.shopinvest.com.br/infofundos/fundos/ConteudoTabelaRentabilidade.do?cdSgmtoProdt=1).

Comment: Feito! Obrigado!